# LinQ OrderBy and OrderByDescending not working in DateTime field

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

Given the same list, OrderBy and OrderByDescending on DateTime fields makes no diferent output:

**List 1**
[image]

**List 2**
[image]

"Fecha" field is `DateTime`.

This is the list:

```
ID  Movimiento_Anterior_ID  Cliente_ID  Fecha                    Monto      Tipo_Movimiento Venta_ID
6   3                       1020        2016-08-17 17:28:05.323  3940.000   NULL            NULL
5   3                       1020        2016-08-17 16:16:26.927  3817.000   NULL            NULL
4   3                       1020        2016-08-17 16:16:01.023  3694.000   NULL            NULL
3   -1                      1020        2016-08-17 16:15:23.937  3571.000   NULL            NULL
2   1                       15          2016-08-17 16:14:19.000  2091.000   NULL            NULL
1   -1                      15          2016-08-17 16:13:52.510  369.000    NULL            NULL
```

Comment: @JesseGood No, look at the count, it says 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, I have no idea why, but the `DefaultIfEmpty()` is causing EF query provider to remove (ignore) the previous order by expressions from the generated SQL query. Weird behavior, but good to be known.

To get the intendended ordering, either remove `DefaultIfEmpty()` (I see no benefit of using it in such query), or move the `OrderBy` / `OrderByDescending` **after** the `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: It appears there used to be a Microsoft Connect issue about it, but it no longer is available. I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7615289/906773) which explains more.

Comment: @JesseGood Good catch! Then I'm going to mark this as dupe.